# double alignment using string.format

Tags: c#

I was trying to align doubles using string.format and display them on a tooltip.

I used:
string.Format("{0,15:N2}", number);

but the results come out as:

```
   1234.56
    00.00
```

It seems some of the numbers are narrower than the space. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a fixed-width font such as Courier New or Consolas if you want all the individual digits to line up.

Comment: No – numbers line up just fine in most fonts because they’re all the same width (new style figures). The problem is getting the decimal points below each other which isn’t possible using only string formatting.